# Controlling FTP server with PHP

Tags: php, linux, ftp, vsftpd

I have been searching the internet for an answer to my question "Can PHP control a FTP server like Vsftpd", however could not find anything.

What I looking for is a way for PHP to control what users can connect to my FTP server.

What I also want to do is limit the space users can use on my server. So once a user uploads something, a check is done to make sure the space the user has left can store the file that is being uploaded. If the file is too large, kill the upload.

I've looked at the vsftpd.log, however it only seems to log transactions whenever the request is finished, and not when initiated.

Is what I want possible? If so, how?

Kind regards,
Jesse

Comment: Why are you trying to build an ftp server with PHP instead of using an existing ftp server?

Comment: As I can't hook any existing FTP servers up with my PHP scripts. As I want to check what users log in and what they upload, checking it against records in my database etc.

Comment: And none of the existing modules for *insert favorite ftp server here* already do that?

Comment: I couldn't find any. Thats why I am asking here.